# HomeGroup network setup

Tags: networking, router, home-server

I'm having a problem setting up home group. My home sever pc (win7 Home Premium) connects directly to the internet, I shared it's internet connection to one of its ethernet (lan) cards which is then plugged directly into the WAN port on my wifi router using a cross-over network cable. All the computers (win7) in the house connects to the wifi router and can access the internet fine and see each other in windows Home Group, but none of them can see my home server pc. please help.

update:
could it be a router setting?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have them all connected to the router and  the internet being run directly to the router?

Comment: yes, i have a wireless "broadband" internet connection which works via a small usb device plugged into my server pc. unfortunately the usb device cannot be plugged into the router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be this -

1. You server gets its IP address from your ISP.
2. The wifi router is providing private IP addresses to the computers connected to it.
3. The wifi router is probably doing NAT.

If this is the case, then you server is on a different network than the rest of the home computers. Essentially it is just another computer on the internet.

Please check the ip addresses of the server and of the computers connecting via the wifi, if they are in different ranges then that is the problem.

I think you should be able to connect the server to the wifi router in the same way as the computers in the home network.

Please let us know about the IP address ranges.

Comment: the wifi router is running as a DHCP, so the computers connected to it do indeed have different ip range than the server. trying your alternate connection idea now, will let you know in a minute if it worked

Comment: no luck. it did not work

Comment: the ip ranges are vastly different 192.168.. vs 41...

Comment: Your server might have more than one ip address now. Does more than one adapter show up on the server?

Comment: i'm running a fit-pc2i as a the server, its a bit confusing as its got 2 Ethernet adapters and a wifi adapter and then my wireless broadband usb device creates a fake Ethernet adapter and a broadband connection adapter, all a have different ip addresses on different ranges, so I disabled the one unused Ethernet apter and WiFi adapter

Comment: Can you connect the remaining ethernet adapter to the wifi router?

Comment: yes. i tried that, then all computer can connect to the home group and see the server, but then the internet doesn't work any more

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Traceroutes to an internet computer, routing tables, defaults gateways?

Comment: will have a look tomorrow and let you know, thank you for all the help

Comment: Finally got it to work! The server is connected to the internet, this connection is shared to Ethernet1 which is connected to the WAN port on the router. Then the server's Ethernet2 is connected to one of the LAN ports on the router. The trick is to start-up the connections in the correct order, first have the lan connection running then only connect the internet connection

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working